# If a finite field $K$ has solutions of $x^2\pm x+1=0$ then $|K|\equiv 1 \mod 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to do an exercise in which $K$ is a finite field of characteristic $p\neq 3$. I want to prove that if $K$ has solutions of $x^2\pm x+1=0$, then $|K|\equiv 1 \mod 3$.

In the same exercise I was also asked to prove that $K$ has a primitive cube root of unity if and only if $|K|\equiv 1 \mod 3$. This part I did manage to prove and I think it might be useful for the question above.

What I have tried is to assume there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $\alpha^2+\alpha +1$=0. If we had $\alpha=1$, then $1+1+1=0$, but this is not possible because the characteristic is not $3$. So $\alpha \neq 1.$ Now we know $0=\alpha^2+\alpha +1=\frac{\alpha^3-1}{\alpha-1}$, so $\alpha^3=1$. I do not know how to show that $\alpha^2\neq 1$ . If I did, I could conclude that $\alpha$ is a primitive cube root of unity and then use the result in the second paragraph. Any ideas in how to prove this will be very useful.

Also, I am a bit confused by the $\pm$ sign in the equation. I do not know if it means that we have solutions for both equations or if it means that we have a solution for one of them. Maybe someone who has more familiarity with this topic knows what makes more sense in this context and can clarify that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha\not=1$ there is no possibility that $\alpha^2=1$.

Comment: Hint 2: $X^2-X+1$ is the equation satisfied by a $6$-th root of unity.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If $\beta^2-\beta+1=0$, then $\beta $ is a root of the cyclotomic polynomial $\phi_6$ and is therefore a primitive sixth root of unity. Is that right? And I also have that this implies $|K|\equiv 1 \mod 6$, so in particular, $|K|\equiv 1 \mod 3$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're essentially there. I am slightly uneasy when you say "the cyclotomic polynomial" as  I am not sure where you mean that polynomial lives, But sure $\beta^6=1$ and as clearly $\beta^2\not=1$ we get that $\beta^3=-1$ and are done.

Comment: If $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha \neq 1$, then $\alpha$ is an element of order $3$ in the multiplicative group $K^{\times}$. By Lagrange’s theorem from group theory, we get that $3$ divides $|K^{\times}|=|K|-1$.

Answer (score 2):

An answer is given in the comments.

Let me remark that if the characteristic of $K$ is $2$ then $x^2-x+1=x^2+x+1$ so we may assume it is not.

From completing the square the roots of $x^2-x+1$ are $z=\frac12(1+\xi)$ where $\xi^2=-3$.

Assuming for simplicity that $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ ($p$ prime) we can now say that the roots are in $K$ if and only if $-3$ is a square. By Gauss's quadratic reciprocity law
$$
\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac{p}3\right)
$$
and the latter symbol is $=1$ if and only if $p\equiv1\bmod 3$.

Comment: Nice use of quadratic reciprocity. But Lagrange’s theorem from group theory suffices.

Comment: @Ihf Of course, but I think it was interesting to show this approach that in fact can be extended to all quadratic polynomials (at least)

Comment: (+1) I had the same idea when looking at the question but "Assuming for simplicity that $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ ($p$ prime)" is not "for simplicity". It is a true restriction, i.e. your answer is interesting but partial. E.g. in $\Bbb F_{5^2},$ $-3$ is a square but not the square of an element of $\Bbb F_5.$